# SQL Query That Should Return Least two days record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table "abc" where i store timestamp having multiple records let suppose

```
1334034000  Date:10-April-2012
1334126289  Date:11-April-2012 
1334291399  Date:13-April-2012
```

I want to build a sql query where I can find at first attempt the records having last two day values and so second time the next two days . . .

Example:

```
Select *,dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created)) from notes
where dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created)) > dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created)) -2
order by dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created))
```

this query returns all the records date wise but we need very most two days record.

Please suggest accordingly. 
Thanks in advance

Edited:

If today is 13 April and our table has max day 10, 9, 8, . . . april then we have to show the 10, 9 April and his last date records

Comment: so just to be sure, each one of your rows has a timestamp telling the creation date of that row, right?

Comment: yes, but the dates is not sure either exactly be the with in the last two days. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't understood everything after the "yes, ", can you please rephrase that?

Comment: would this solve your problem?
 "SELECT * FROM notes WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-i_created<172800" then the previous 2 days you multiply the number by 2 and so on

Comment: Probably, it would be better to add some more sample data and your expected result in a tabular format to understand the question.

Comment: @adnan.shammout: actually it is not sure exactly before the two days then it is fine but the problem is that we need previous two days either it may be consecutive or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query -

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
  JOIN (SELECT date FROM table GROUP BY date DESC LIMIT 2) t2
    ON t1.date = t2.date
```

It will show all records with date = '11-April-2012' and '13-April-2012'.

Is this what you want?

---

**Edited:**

```
SELECT
  t1.*, t2.date
FROM
  notes t1
JOIN (SELECT
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created)) date
      FROM
        notes
      GROUP BY
        date DESC
      LIMIT
        2
  ) t2
ON
  DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.i_created)) = t2.date
```

Comment: Accordingly it becomes -----   SELECT t1.*,dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.i_created)) FROM notes t1
  JOIN (SELECT *,dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created)) FROM notes GROUP BY dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(i_created)) DESC LIMIT 2) t2
    ON t1.dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.i_created)) = t2.dayofmonth(FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.i_created)) but dit't work

Answer (score 0):

Add `limit 2` to the end of your query

Comment: he's not limiting the number of results to two items but rather to items within the last two days.

Comment: Ahh, I had trouble understanding the question.

Comment: @kjones: exactly not two records but having the most recent two dates!!